# Uniform circular motion - relative velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Suppose two particles start at y=2 and move along the circumference of a circle of radius 2 units, opposite to each other at uniform angular velocity. 
If we have to calculate the velocity of one with respect to the other, we have to consider this as a problem as one involving non-inertial reference frames ?

Comment: Just write the velocities in vector form considering centre of circle as origin. The difference of the vectors is $\vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1}$ i.e. the relative velocity.

Comment: Considering it inertial or non inertial doesn't matter here because you are calculating velocity here not force..! And if you think about it first  rel. velocity will be -2v and then 2v. (Directions arb.)

Comment: Yes, the direction of velocities are changing, so this is non-inertial frame problem. But the motion is circular, so analysis is easier than any random irregular motion.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of reference frame is yours. If you choose any inertial frame, the relative velocity follows from subtracting the individual velocities from each other. If you choose a coordinate frame rotating at the same angular velocity as the particles, then the individual and relative velocities will vanish.

Answer (score 0):

You will just find the relative velocity in the normal way.
Let the velocities of the two objects 1 and 2 be $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$.

If you want the velocity of object 2 relative to object 1 think of the problem as adding a velocity to object 1 $(-\vec v_1)$ to object 1 $(\vec v_1 + (- \vec v_1)=0)$ and then also to object 2, $(\vec v_2 + (- \vec v_1) = \vec v_2 -\vec v_1)$ as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

Thus far you do not need to worry as to whether the frames are non inertial of not but if you then start trying applying Newton's laws in the frame of object 1 then you will.